# insertMany does not work properly while streaming in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `Node.js`, `mongoose.js` and `mongoDB` in `M0 Sandbox (General)` atlas tier. I want to use streaming for better optimization of resources usages. here's my code:

```
let counter = 0;
let batchCounter = 0;
const batchSize = 500;
const tagFollowToBeSaved = [];

let startTime;

USER.find({}, { _id: 1 }).cursor()
  .on('data', (id) => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      startTime = process.hrtime();
    }
    if (counter === batchSize) {
      counter = 0;
      const [s2] = process.hrtime();
      console.log('finding ', batchSize, ' data took: ', s2 - startTime[0]);
      TAG_FOLLOW.insertMany(tagFollowToBeSaved, { ordered: false })
        .then((ok) => {
          batchCounter += 1;
          const [s3] = process.hrtime();
          console.log(`batch ${batchCounter} took: ${s3 - s2}`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error in inserting following: ', error);
        });
      // deleting array
      tagFollowToBeSaved.splice(0, tagFollowToBeSaved.length);
    }
    else {
      counter += 1;
      tagFollowToBeSaved.push({
        tagId: ObjectId('5e81ba5a5c86d7215cdc9c88'),
        followedBy: id,
      });
    }
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error while streaming: ', error);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('END');
  });
```

What I'm doing:

1. first I read `_id`s from `USER` collection of **200k** users using streams API with `cursor`
2. check whether the number of reads `_id`s has reached the batch size limit, if so, I'm going to insert these data to `TAG_FOLLOW` model.

All the `console.log`s are for analysis purposes and you can ignore them.

However `insertMany` does not work properly. because I'm monitoring database while inserting data, **It seems it inserts about 100 data instead of 500 per batch size without throwing any error**, therefore I'm losing 400 data per batch which is so unacceptable!

Although I changed the `batchSize` value, it does not work anyway and I'm going to lose some data per batch.

So what is the problem? what is the better approach for saving a bunch of large data in an optimized and ensured way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With your approach how do you plan to insert the last batch if its size is less than `batchSize`?

Comment: We can first use the `count` function to get the number of documents, then divide it with appropriate factor @TheeSritabtim

Comment: You said when you changed `batchSize` it didn't work anyway. Did you try changing batchSize to 100? How many rows were inserted?

I think it might be safer to just allocate a new array like this `tagFollowToBeSaved  = []` instead of emptying and reusing the `tagFollowToBeSaved ` array reference